# Removing duplicates from a Array

Tags: java, algorithm

[image]

I am dealing with the following problem from my data structure book. I have come up with the solution as suggested by this text . I basically found all the duplicates and labelled them some arbitrary number like 666 and then removed them from the array.

My question to everyone is - is my solution is exactly as the text suggested?
- also what is a more effective method to solve this problem?

Here is the  complete code (LOOK at the nodups method to see my solution)

```
public class HighArray {

    private long[] a;
    private int nElems;

    public HighArray(int max) {

        a = new long[max];
        nElems = 0;
    }

    public boolean find(long searchKey) {
        int j;
        for (j = 0; j < nElems; j++)
            if (a[j] == searchKey)
                break;

        if (j == nElems) {
            return false;
        }

        else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public void insert(long value) {

        a[nElems] = value;
        nElems++;
    }

    public void noDups() {
        int i = 0;
        long compareKey;

        while (i < nElems) {

            compareKey = a[i];

            for (int j = 0; j < nElems; j++) {
                if (j != i && a[j] != 666) {
                    if (a[j] == compareKey) {
                        a[j] = 666;
                    }
                }
                j++;
            }

            i++;
        }

        for (int k = 0; k < nElems; k++) {
            if (a[k] == 666) {
                delete(a[k]);
            }
        }

    }

    public boolean delete(long value) {

        int j;
        for (j = 0; j < nElems; j++)
            if (a[j] == value)
                break;

        if (j == nElems) {
            return false;
        }

        else {
            for (int k = j; k < nElems - 1; k++)
                a[k] = a[k + 1];
            nElems--;
            return true;
        }
    }

    public long removeMax() {

        if (nElems != 0) {
            long maxValue = a[0];

            for (int i = 0; i < nElems; i++) {
                if (a[i] > maxValue)
                    maxValue = a[i];
            }

            delete(maxValue);
            return maxValue;
        }

        else {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    public void display() {

        for (int i = 0; i < nElems; i++) {
            System.out.println(a[i]);
        }
    }

}
```

The following class has main method.

```
public class HighArrayApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HighArray arr = new HighArray(100);

        arr.insert(2);
        arr.insert(2);
        arr.insert(3);
        arr.insert(4);
        arr.insert(4);
        arr.insert(5);

        arr.display();

        arr.noDups();

        System.out.println("-------------------------");

        arr.display();

    }

}
```

I highly appreciate any suggestions and i am open to all kinds of approaches that attempt a more effective algorithm for this problem.

Comment: You can add elements of long[] to a Set (HashSet) and convert the HashSet to array to eliminate duplicates

Comment: Does it work?  Make sure you test some cases where there are three or more duplicates right next to each other in the array.  I suspect you will run into problems.

Comment: @user2733436 would you like to see a lambda expression of what you try to achieve?

Comment: @jack while that would work it defeats the point of learning algorithms to remove duplicates as the `Set` Does the work.

Comment: This algorithm is not correct if the array happens to contain 666 already.  To fix this, test the compareKey for being 666 and set a flag to true if you find it, and then loop for (int j = i+1; j < nElems; j++).  Then, when you remove the "666" entries, skip the first if the flag is true.  Of course kruemel's solution is algorithmically faster and is probably the desired solution.

Comment: Yes this is working. I just used 666 as the text suggested i could use some value/number i wouldn't need as a flag...so i choose 666.

Comment: @dbc i just posted another question, is it possible for you to look?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You solution is valid but as you said, I think there is a more efficient approach. I also think the given text implies this (*"One approach is ..."*, *"Another approach is..."*).

Comparing each element with the others is `O(n^2)`.

If you sort the array first, you can remove duplicates with a single walk through the array.

Sorting is `O(n log n)`, walking through is `O(n)`.

The total complexity is then `O( n log n) + O(n) = O(n log n)`.

This solution is valid, as the text clearly states that the order of the objects may be changed.

Comment: I'm not good with time complexity so maybe you could clear this up for me. How can you take `O(n log n)` then add something to it, and still have the result be only `O(n log n)`?

Comment: This is how addition in Landau notation works. It is obvious if you think about n being really large. In O(n log n) + O(n), the O(n log n) part will grow much faster, making O(n) irrelevant.

Comment: So, once i sort the array or have a sorted array, and remove the duplicated my complexity would be O(n) ? I can see that the solution i posted is n^2 since i have nested loops.

Comment: @kruemel hey i just posted another question is it possible for you to take a look?

Answer (score 3):

**You can through this with less code by using Lambda Expression**

Code:

```
public class LambdaTest     
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {

         List<Integer> objList = Arrays.asList(1,1,2,3,2,4,5,2,5);
         objList .forEach(i -> System.out.print(" " + i));
         System.out.println();
         List<Integer> noDub =objList.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
         noDub.forEach(i -> System.out.print(" " + i));
    } 
}
```

output:

```
1 1 2 3 2 4 5 2 5 

1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: are you using some kind of built in function. collectors is built in to java if i am not mistaken?

Comment: all new functions from java 8. if u r interested in, I would be more than happy to share you what I have figured out so far :)

Comment: Yeah i would definitely be interested . In my solution i did not use any built in function as the text suggested otherwise. :) upvoted u already

Comment: which is impressive to me. I'll study your solution for sure cuz I want to know what's going on in beneath of set function. my email is in my page. +1 u already too haha sounds kind of funny but seriously I did

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of better and faster data structures for this. Why not use a HashSet?

Example

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        Integer [] arr = new Integer[]{4, 3, 1, 2, 4, 3, 2};
        Set<Integer> hs = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(arr));
        System.out.println(hs);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ugh, you'd think someone might add a couple lines of example code. This should be a comment in its present form.

Comment: Well i have not learned about HashSet yet...that's why i used this approach

Comment: @user2733436 my sample is much easier than that. if you don't understand it lemme know so I can through more explanation for you

Answer (score 1):

Your function performs the way the text implies, which unfortunately is a horrible way to do it.

First, you are assuming 666 won't be a possible value, which may be false, and in design even if it is temporarily true that may change with future changes to your program.

Second, the HighArray class should not be keeping an array of longs if you expect to be adding and deleting from the list. An ArrayList or your own implementation of a linked list would be more appropriate, since the order of your items matters.

If you must use the given HighArray class, then the simplest method would to be to convert the array `a` into a HashSet, which will keep track of all unique values. Then turn the HashSet back into an array.

```
Set<Long> uniqueNumbers = new HashSet<Long>(Arrays.asList(a));
a = uniqueNumbers.toArray(new long[uniqueNumbers.size()]);
```

Creating and managing the set is `O(n lg(n))` overall complexity, and converting it back to an array is `O(n)` which is much better than the `O(n^2)` complexity of your original method.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm described in the book is akin to a bubble sort. The easiest way is to do this is to use two nested loops.

```
for (int i=0; i < a.length;i++) {
    long ref = a[i];
    for (int j=i+1; j < a.length; j++) {
        if(a[j] == ref) {
            a[j] = Long.MIN_VALUE;
        }
    }
}
```

I've left out the cleanup part.